# How to connect two docker containers, one containing hazelcast in memory data grid, and one containing war file

Tags: spring, docker, containers

I have two docker containers, one with hazelcast java application (the core for the web application - jar package) and one with rest service for the web application (war package). I'm using docker-compose to build up whole project in docker which looks like this:

```
version: "3" 

services:

 escomled_datagrid:
    image: escomled/escomled_datagrid
    build:
      context: ./sh_scripts/escomled_data_grid

 tomcat:
    image: escomled/tomcat
    build:
      context: ./tomcat/app
    ports:
      - 8585:8080
    depends_on: 
      - escomled_datagrid
    links:
      - escomled_datagrid:escomled_datagrid
```

I also have Dockerfile for each container:

-escomled_datagrid:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine as build
WORKDIR /EscomledML
COPY  ./. ./
COPY  ./escomled.properties 
        /home/escomled/escomled_server/config/escomled.properties

CMD ["sh","/EscomledML/escomled_data_grid.sh","start"]


EXPOSE 8085
```

-tomcat

```
FROM tomcat:8.5-alpine
COPY ./sample.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
COPY ./escomled-rest.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
COPY  ./escomled.properties 
       /home/escomled/escomled_server/config/escomled.properties

RUN sh -c 'touch /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/sample.war'
RUN sh -c 'touch /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/escomled-rest.war'

EXPOSE 8080
```

First container uses sh script in the runtime. 
This way everyting works fine, the containers start and stay active.
The only problem is that they dont see each other, hazelcast server starts and waits for "member" to connect, war file (hazelcast member) also starts, but they dont "see" each other and wont connect. I put in the docker-compose file "links" and "depends on" tags, but that wont help.

The code for the project works fine when I start it localy, first I start data grid server as java application, then I start the tomcat containing rest service and the connection is established in no time.

So my question is, how do I link this two containers so they can see each other and work together?

Answer (score 0):

try putting the containers in the same "network" by specifying the network bridge

```
version: "3" 

services:

escomled_datagrid:
    image: escomled/escomled_datagrid
    build:
    context: ./sh_scripts/escomled_data_grid
    networks:
      - networknamename


tomcat:
    image: escomled/tomcat
    build:
    context: ./tomcat/app
   ports:
      - 8585:8080
   depends_on: 
      - escomled_datagrid
   links:
      - escomled_datagrid:escomled_datagrid
   networks:
     - networknamename


networks:

    networknamename:
        driver: bridge
```

Comment: Hi Rutger, thank you for the reply, this is not working as well, both containers start but they still dont see each other, I tried overlay driver as well and still not working

Comment: Can we connect somehow, I would appreciate your help.. I'm stuck 3 days with this problem.

Comment: I am at my work at the moment, I will try to find some time this evening to recreate your problem, but I am far from an expert. Hope I can help

Comment: Thank you very much sir! Do you plan to connect with me somehow so I can show you everything in the project and chat?

Comment: I am quite busy at the moment but if you provide me your email I would like to 
 try help you out. Containers on the default bridge network can only access each other by IP addresses, unless you use the --link option, which is considered legacy. On a user-defined bridge network, containers can resolve each other by name or alias.

Comment: try running these 3 comments docker network create -d bridge br0  : docker network connect br0 escomled_datagrid
docker network connect br0 tomcat

Comment: xelcina@gmail.com , you can reach me on this email address, thank you